# Form data value from view - Javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I'm trying to append data to a form data from a view, but it returns `undefined`
My code:

HTML:

`<input type="text" id="idItem">`

`<button id="idBtn" type="button" onclick="myMethod()">Aceptar</button>`

JAVASCRIPT:

```
function myMethod(){
    var formData = new FormData()
    formData.append("nombre",$('#idItem').value) //input-text
}
```

Any suggest?

Thanks.

Comment: RTD: http://api.jquery.com/val. Closing as a typo

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to change this `$('#idItem').value` => `$('#idItem').val()`